# Android: Communication between activity and service

Tags: android

I am a little new to Android so please help me understand this.
While reading service from the android developer website I found this paragraph for which I couldn't come up with an example:

> If the service does not also provide binding, the intent delivered with startService() is the only mode of communication between the application component and the service. However, if you want the service to send a result back, then the client that starts the service can create a PendingIntent for a broadcast (with getBroadcast()) and deliver it to the service in the Intent that starts the service. The service can then use the broadcast to deliver a result.

I know there are other ways also to send result back to activity but I see the above explained logic as simpler than any other way. Please help me understand this with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `BroadcastReceiver` or `ResultReceiver` to receive the result from `Service`. In this time, I want to guide you about using `ResultReceiver`:

First, create a class to receive the result inside your activity and extend `ResultReceiver`:

```
private class MyReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
    public MyReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        /*
        * We can get the type of data passed from Service to Activity:
        * int --> getInt("key")
        * String --> getString("key")
        * boolean --> getBoolean("key")
        * /
        if (resultCode == MyService.RUNNING) {
            String str = resultData.getString("dataStringKey"); // get information within the key, i.e. "dataString"
            myTextView.setText(str); // set the text to get the data received
        }

        if (resultCode == MyService.SERVICE_STOPPED) {
            // do something, such as get data received with the key
        }
    }
}
```

In your `Service`:

```
public static final int RUNNING = 0;
public static final int SERVICE_DESTROYED = 1;
private ResultReceiver receiver;
private Bundle resultData;
private int status;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    resultData = new Bundle();
    status = RUNNING;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
    String dataFromActivity = intent.getStringExtra("text");
    /*
    * send result/information to activity, also we can put:
    * int --> putInt("key", value)
    * boolean --> putBoolean("key", value)
    * String --> putString("key", "My string.")
    * /
    resultData.putString("dataStringKey", "Hi, this is a String data.");
    receiver.send(status, resultData);

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    status = SERVICE_DESTROYED;
    receiver.send(status, resultData);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

When you trigger the `Service`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("text", "Text to be passed to Service.");
intent.putExtra("receiver", new MyReceiver(new Handler()));
this.startService(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent` to sent data from your `Activity` to `Service`, and use a [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to sent data from your Service to Activity.

Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/Antarix/8131277) on how to use LocalBroadcastManager.

```
public class LocalBroadcastExampleActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.log_list);

        Button buttonStartService = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        buttonStartService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Register MessageService in Manifest to work
                Intent intent = new Intent(LocalBroadcastExampleActivity.this, MessageService.class);
                 intent.putExtra("mydatakey", myString);  // <--- set data to send to service
                startService(new Intent(LocalBroadcastExampleActivity.this, MessageService.class));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // Unregister since the activity is paused.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(
                mMessageReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // Register to receive messages.
        // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
        // with actions named "custom-event-name".
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
        super.onResume();
    }

    // Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
    // with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted.
    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
        }
    };

    public class MessageService extends Service {

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String mydata = intent.getStringExtra("mydatakey"); // <--- retrieve data sent from Service
            sendMessage();
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        // Send an Intent with an action named "custom-event-name". The Intent
        // sent should
        // be received by the ReceiverActivity.
        private void sendMessage() {
            Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
            Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
            // You can also include some extra data.
            intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

    }

}
```

But in my case I prefer using event bus Libraries such as [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) , [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) which more easier to use and less time consuming.